# JMETER: Replace hardcoded request param with new value generated at runtime?

Tags: regex, variables, runtime, jmeter, extractor

In the web app I am testing, a unique authorization code is generated at runtime and submitted with each http request during that [web browser] session.  Jmeter script recorder stores the hardcoded value, which again is only valid during that session.

I can use the Regular Expression Extractor to capture the authorization code, which is generated on the 10th http request in the test plan.  I need to tell JMETER to use this new authorization code in all subsequent http requests in the test.  I can manually replace all subsequent occurrences of the code with the new value extracted, but this would mean hundreds of manual changes.

Is there any way to tell JMETER that from a given point going forward, ignore the hardcoded value and use the value extracted during the 10th call.  This is important because each test plan has hundreds of calls and there will be multiple test plans for the web site.

THX

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hard-coded value as in runtime it will be quite hard to replace it. Use a JMeter Variable instead. Something like `${AUTH_CODE}` wherever it is required.

Make sure that you use the same Reference Name `AUTH_CODE` in your Regular Expression Extractor at 10th request of your test plan.

If your Test Plan contains multiple thread groups use JMeter Property instead. See [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) for step-by-step implementation guide